# Set default namespace mapping in lxml

Tags: python, lxml

When handling XML with lxml my code ends up looking like the following:

```py
from lxml import etree

NSMAP = {
  'ns1': 'https://example.com/ns1/',
  'ns2': 'https://example.com/ns2/',
}

root = etree.parse('/some/file.xml')
root.find(..., namespaces=NSMAP)
root.iterfind(..., namespaces=NSMAP)
root.xpath(..., namespaces=NSMAP)
```

Is there a way to omit the repetitious `namespaces=NSMAP` and set it as default for an element?

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify your code by setting the default namespace for an element in lxml. You can do this by creating a custom Element class that includes the default namespace. Here's an example of how to achieve this:

```
from lxml import etree

class DefaultNamespaceElement(etree.ElementBase):
    def find(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().find(path, namespaces=NSMAP, *args, **kwargs)

    def iterfind(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().iterfind(path, namespaces=NSMAP, *args, **kwargs)

    def xpath(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().xpath(path, namespaces=NSMAP, *args, **kwargs)

# Create a custom parser with the DefaultNamespaceElement class
parser = etree.XMLParser(target=DefaultNamespaceElement)

# Parse your XML file using the custom parser
root = etree.parse('/some/file.xml', parser)

# Now you can use the find, iterfind, and xpath methods without specifying namespaces
result = root.find('...', namespaces=NSMAP)  # No need to specify namespaces=NSMAP
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: I did use AI to make my englishes sentences good